# OBIEE 11g cache analysis with different variables using agent

Tags: obiee

I have an analysis with many result records (if I don't filter special column in that, I will get Max exceeded number of records error), so I used a PresentationVariable in my filter ( ex : MyColumn = @{MyPresentationVariable} )
now I want to create an agent to seed cache for this analysis , but I can not find a way to run it with all available values for "MyColumn" . For example MyColumn can have value between 2000 and 2017 and I want a way to run the agent 18 times, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

So you basically want to populate the cache with more data than your Presentation Server allows for rendering?

Question: Why? Isn't that a rather clear sign that you should rethink what you are doing in the first place?

Comment: thanks Chris , consider that I have just 3 dimension with 7 values for each one (7*7*7* = 343 case) and a date dimension with 30 days in a month (343 * 30 = 10290 case), for a month it's not that much and it can be the criteria of my analysis, but the user wants to select the month as a prompt and I just want to run analysis for all months before user doing it (one by one at night for example)so the next day, user don't have to wait for each month--- I know I can do it with sth like ODI , but I want if there is a way in OBIEE

Comment: If you have 10.2k records being fetched and getting issues then my first point is even more valid: you shouldn't get an error and something is seriously wrong and you need to rethink what you are doing and how you are doing it. Caching that is peanuts.